# Shared variables between unique pairs (columns) giving errors with widyr() in R

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate how many species are shared between region pairs. So if species A, B, and C all occur in, say, the US and Canada, but species D only occurs in Canada, then the number of shared species for the US-Canada pair == 3. I've used widyr() package in R to do this on a large dataset (>10,000 species in 50 countries), but I'm getting two errors:

1. If I analyze the whole dataset, some region pairs are missing, whereas if I just subset the two regions, then it works (gives the number of shared species for that pair).
   and 2) I tried with just a subset of the regions, and I get different answers for how many species are shared, compared to using the full dataset.

I've seen some similar posts about calculating the distance between pairs, and unique pairs, but it's not quite what I'm trying to do. I've never used widyr before and I can't figure out what the mistake is - I'm wondering if it's something with "first" and "last"?

```
# sample.dat.sub dput below - it's long but I wasn't sure I coudl reproduce the problem with only a few rows

# sample.dat.sub has cols "species_id" and "rgn_id"

## get col names
spp_ids <- sample.dat.sub %>% distinct(species_id) %>% as.character()
rgn_ids <- sample.dat.sub %>% distinct(rgn_id) 
rgn_ids <- rgn_ids$rgn_id
rgn_ids <- as.character(rgn_ids)

## find pairs
pairs.df <- sample.dat.sub %>%
  group_by(species_id) %>%
  arrange(rgn_id) %>%
  # maybe this is the problem?
  mutate(rgn1 = first(rgn_id), rgn2 = last(rgn_id))  

result.df <- pairs.df %>%
  group_by(rgn1, rgn2) %>%
  # number of unique species that each region pair shares
  summarize(n_spp = n_distinct(species_id))

# THE PROBLEM:
result.df %>% filter(rgn1 == 134) # says 134-136 have 27 shared species, but if I just analyzed those 2 reigons alone, it says they share 75 species...

## test the sample

sample.test <- sample.dat.sub %>% filter(rgn_id %in% c(134,136))

# get col names
test.spp_ids <- sample.test %>% distinct(species_id) %>% as.character()
test.rgn_ids <- sample.test %>% distinct(rgn_id) 
test.rgn_ids <- test.rgn_ids$rgn_id
test.rgn_ids <- as.character(test.rgn_ids)

# pairs
test.pairs.df <- sample.test %>%
  group_by(species_id) %>%
  arrange(rgn_id) %>%
  mutate(rgn1 = first(rgn_id), rgn2 = last(rgn_id)) 
test.pairs.df 

test.result.df <- test.pairs.df %>%
  group_by(rgn1, rgn2) %>%
  summarize(n_spp = n_distinct(species_id))

test.result.df %>% arrange(desc(n_spp)) # now it says 75 species shared

## SAMPLE DATA

sample.dat.sub <- structure(list(species_id = c("Brc-378165", "Brc-378165", "Brc-378165", 
"Chn-0721ac0c-7d19-46fa-9dcc-02da54310867", "Chn-0721ac0c-7d19-46fa-9dcc-02da54310867", 
"Chn-0721ac0c-7d19-46fa-9dcc-02da54310867", "Chn-46f58c2c-1280-4f6a-a148-e854c19246fe", 
"Chn-46f58c2c-1280-4f6a-a148-e854c19246fe", "Chn-4a9f789f-84e4-4da2-b520-c754b804a303", 
"Chn-4a9f789f-84e4-4da2-b520-c754b804a303", "Chn-4a9f789f-84e4-4da2-b520-c754b804a303", 
"Chn-5b98a280-b9a0-435b-8ed9-87b3f63fc29b", "Chn-5b98a280-b9a0-435b-8ed9-87b3f63fc29b", 
"Chn-5b98a280-b9a0-435b-8ed9-87b3f63fc29b", "Chn-eff8756a-9d9f-4430-886b-4a0badfed55d", 
"Chn-eff8756a-9d9f-4430-886b-4a0badfed55d", "Chn-eff8756a-9d9f-4430-886b-4a0badfed55d", 
"Chn-f031838d-0a64-4288-8d25-04c0ab44ad67", "Chn-f41af29f-5e40-4cb4-8862-220e6e64b329", 
"Chn-f41af29f-5e40-4cb4-8862-220e6e64b329", "Chn-f41af29f-5e40-4cb4-8862-220e6e64b329", 
"Fis-10903", "Fis-10993", "Fis-10993", "Fis-10993", "Fis-112580", 
"Fis-112580", "Fis-112580", "Fis-112580", "Fis-112582", "Fis-112582", 
"Fis-112582", "Fis-112590", "Fis-112590", "Fis-112590", "Fis-112688", 
"Fis-112688", "Fis-112688", "Fis-112689", "Fis-112689", "Fis-112689", 
"Fis-112689", "Fis-112706", "Fis-112706", "Fis-112706", "Fis-112706", 
"Fis-112822", "Fis-112822", "Fis-112822", "Fis-113904", "Fis-113904", 
"Fis-114088", "Fis-114088", "Fis-114088", "Fis-114098", "Fis-114098", 
"Fis-114098", "Fis-114124", "Fis-114124", "Fis-114124", "Fis-114187", 
"Fis-11429", "Fis-11429", "Fis-11429", "Fis-114378", "Fis-114378", 
"Fis-114378", "Fis-114615", "Fis-114615", "Fis-114615", "Fis-114618", 
"Fis-114618", "Fis-114618", "Fis-114618", "Fis-114623", "Fis-114623", 
"Fis-114623", "Fis-114937", "Fis-114937", "Fis-114937", "Fis-114940", 
"Fis-114940", "Fis-114940", "Fis-115015", "Fis-115015", "Fis-115015", 
"Fis-115342", "Fis-115352", "Fis-115352", "Fis-115352", "Fis-115623", 
"Fis-115623", "Fis-115623", "Fis-115798", "Fis-115798", "Fis-115798", 
"Fis-115798", "Fis-115821", "Fis-115821", "Fis-115821", "Fis-115864", 
"Fis-115864", "Fis-115865", "Fis-115865", "Fis-115865", "Fis-115865", 
"Fis-115865", "Fis-115873", "Fis-115873", "Fis-115873", "Fis-115873", 
"Fis-115957", "Fis-115957", "Fis-115957", "Fis-115963", "Fis-115963", 
"Fis-115963", "Fis-115986", "Fis-115986", "Fis-115986", "Fis-115989", 
"Fis-115989", "Fis-115989", "Fis-116375", "Fis-116375", "Fis-116472", 
"Fis-116479", "Fis-116479", "Fis-116479", "Fis-116737", "Fis-116737", 
"Fis-116737", "Fis-116742", "Fis-116742", "Fis-116742", "Fis-116747", 
"Fis-116747", "Fis-116747", "Fis-116901", "Fis-116901", "Fis-116901", 
"Fis-116910", "Fis-116910", "Fis-116910", "Fis-116926", "Fis-116926", 
"Fis-117119", "Fis-117121", "Fis-117126", "Fis-117126", "Fis-117126", 
"Fis-117130", "Fis-117130", "Fis-117130", "Fis-117220", "Fis-117220", 
"Fis-117220", "Fis-117350", "Fis-117350", "Fis-117350", "Fis-117350", 
"Fis-117358", "Fis-117358", "Fis-117370", "Fis-117370", "Fis-117370", 
"Fis-117375", "Fis-117375", "Fis-117375", "Fis-117773", "Fis-117773", 
"Fis-117773", "Fis-117773", "Fis-118052", "Fis-118052", "Fis-118052", 
"Fis-118058", "Fis-118058", "Fis-118058", "Fis-118058", "Fis-118106", 
"Fis-118106", "Fis-118106", "Fis-118742", "Fis-118742", "Fis-120072", 
"Fis-120072", "Fis-120072", "Fis-120428", "Fis-120428", "Fis-120470", 
"Fis-120470", "Fis-120470", "Fis-120470", "Fis-120470", "Fis-120470", 
"Fis-120669", "Fis-120908", "Fis-120908", "Fis-120908", "Fis-122362", 
"Fis-122362", "Fis-122362", "Fis-123096", "Fis-123121", "Fis-123121", 
"Fis-123121", "Fis-123123", "Fis-123123", "Fis-123123", "Fis-123128", 
"Fis-123128", "Fis-123128", "Fis-123959", "Fis-123959", "Fis-123959", 
"Fis-123975", "Fis-124168", "Fis-124168", "Fis-124204", "Fis-124204", 
"Fis-124208", "Fis-124211", "Fis-124211", "Fis-124211", "Fis-124275", 
"Fis-124275", "Fis-124324", "Fis-124324", "Fis-124376", "Fis-124376", 
"Fis-124376", "Fis-124376", "Fis-124376", "Fis-124378", "Fis-124378", 
"Fis-125137", "Fis-125137", "Fis-125137", "Fis-125137", "Fis-125186", 
"Fis-125235", "Fis-125622", "Fis-125622", "Fis-125622", "Fis-125639", 
"Fis-125639", "Fis-125642", "Fis-125642", "Fis-125886", "Fis-125888", 
"Fis-125893", "Fis-125893", "Fis-125893", "Fis-126085", "Fis-126085", 
"Fis-126140", "Fis-126296", "Fis-126299", "Fis-126299", "Fis-126299", 
"Fis-126681", "Fis-126681", "Fis-126681", "Fis-126951", "Fis-127016", 
"Fis-127016", "Fis-127016", "Fis-127124", "Fis-127433", "Fis-127433", 
"Fis-127444", "Fis-127530", "Fis-127585", "Fis-127585", "Fis-128046", 
"Fis-128046", "Fis-128046", "Fis-128063", "Fis-128093", "Fis-128093", 
"Fis-128093", "Fis-128094", "Fis-128094", "Fis-128110", "Fis-128110", 
"Fis-128236", "Fis-128236", "Fis-128376", "Fis-128376", "Fis-128376", 
"Fis-128376", "Fis-128422", "Fis-128608", "Fis-128608", "Fis-128612", 
"Fis-128612", "Fis-130029", "Fis-130029", "Fis-130029", "Fis-130702", 
"Fis-130702", "Fis-130702", "Fis-130702", "Fis-130709", "Fis-130709", 
"Fis-130709", "Fis-130709", "Fis-130771", "Fis-130806", "Fis-130806", 
"Fis-130806", "Fis-130825", "Fis-130825", "Fis-130825", "Fis-130876", 
"Fis-130876", "Fis-130876", "Fis-130917", "Fis-130917", "Fis-130917", 
"Fis-130921", "Fis-130921", "Fis-131008", "Fis-131178", "Fis-131178", 
"Fis-131312", "Fis-131312", "Fis-131316", "Fis-131316", "Fis-131323", 
"Fis-131323", "Fis-131323", "Fis-131546", "Fis-131546", "Fis-131546", 
"Fis-131546", "Fis-131590", "Fis-131590", "Fis-131590", "Fis-131936", 
"Fis-132003", "Fis-132003", "Fis-132003", "Fis-132010", "Fis-132010", 
"Fis-132010", "Fis-132018", "Fis-132018", "Fis-132018", "Fis-132022", 
"Fis-132022", "Fis-132022", "Fis-132037", "Fis-132037", "Fis-132037", 
"Fis-132059", "Fis-132059", "Fis-132059", "Fis-132062", "Fis-132062", 
"Fis-132062", "Fis-132062", "Fis-132064", "Fis-132064", "Fis-132064", 
"Fis-132076", "Fis-132076", "Fis-132076", "Fis-132087", "Fis-132087", 
"Fis-132142", "Fis-132142", "Fis-132153", "Fis-132153", "Fis-132153", 
"Fis-132157", "Fis-132157", "Fis-132159", "Fis-132159", "Fis-132159", 
"Fis-132167", "Fis-132167", "Fis-132167", "Fis-132169", "Fis-132169", 
"Fis-132169", "Fis-132243", "Fis-132243", "Fis-132243", "Fis-132269", 
"Fis-132269", "Fis-132269", "Fis-132395", "Fis-132433", "Fis-132433", 
"Fis-132433", "Fis-132442", "Fis-132442", "Fis-132442", "Fis-132477", 
"Fis-132477", "Fis-132477", "Fis-132479", "Fis-132479", "Fis-132479", 
"Fis-132487", "Fis-132487", "Fis-132487", "Fis-132488", "Fis-132488", 
"Fis-132488", "Fis-132490", "Fis-132490", "Fis-132490", "Fis-132496", 
"Fis-132597", "Fis-132597", "Fis-132597", "Fis-132597", "Fis-132605", 
"Fis-132605", "Fis-132605", "Fis-132609", "Fis-132609", "Fis-132609", 
"Fis-132643", "Fis-132643", "Fis-132754", "Fis-132754", "Fis-132754", 
"Fis-132762", "Fis-132762", "Fis-132762", "Fis-132763", "Fis-132763", 
"Fis-132763", "Fis-132766", "Fis-132770", "Fis-132808", "Fis-132808", 
"Fis-132808", "Fis-132813", "Fis-132813", "Fis-132813", "Fis-132813", 
"Fis-132814", "Fis-132814", "Fis-132814", "Fis-132966", "Fis-133336", 
"Fis-133336", "Fis-133336", "Fis-133336", "Fis-133346", "Fis-133346", 
"Fis-133350", "Fis-133350", "Fis-133350", "Fis-133356", "Fis-133356", 
"Fis-133356", "Fis-133356", "Fis-133480", "Fis-133508", "Fis-133510", 
"Fis-133512", "Fis-133521", "Fis-133521", "Fis-133521", "Fis-133526", 
"Fis-133537", "Fis-133549", "Fis-133567", "Fis-133567", "Fis-133567", 
"Fis-133571", "Fis-133571", "Fis-133571", "Fis-133572", "Fis-133572", 
"Fis-133572", "Fis-133755", "Fis-133755", "Fis-133755", "Fis-133755", 
"Fis-134025", "Fis-134025", "Fis-134025", "Fis-134029", "Fis-134029", 
"Fis-134029", "Fis-134033", "Fis-134033", "Fis-134057", "Fis-134092", 
"Fis-134103", "Fis-134108", "Fis-134125", "Fis-134130"), rgn_id = c("110", 
"112", "136", "138", "136", "134", "136", "134", "134", "138", 
"136", "134", "136", "138", "134", "138", "136", "138", "138", 
"134", "136", "138", "138", "134", "136", "250", "136", "110", 
"112", "250", "110", "112", "250", "112", "110", "112", "250", 
"110", "112", "110", "136", "250", "250", "136", "112", "110", 
"250", "110", "112", "136", "134", "136", "138", "134", "138", 
"136", "134", "138", "136", "134", "138", "110", "250", "112", 
"112", "110", "250", "112", "110", "250", "110", "250", "136", 
"112", "250", "112", "110", "112", "110", "250", "112", "110", 
"250", "110", "250", "112", "110", "136", "112", "110", "250", 
"110", "112", "112", "250", "110", "136", "112", "110", "250", 
"112", "110", "134", "250", "138", "136", "112", "250", "112", 
"136", "110", "112", "250", "110", "110", "250", "112", "112", 
"250", "110", "112", "250", "110", "136", "134", "138", "250", 
"110", "112", "250", "112", "110", "138", "134", "136", "138", 
"134", "136", "136", "134", "138", "134", "136", "138", "138", 
"136", "138", "138", "250", "112", "110", "134", "138", "136", 
"250", "112", "110", "112", "110", "250", "136", "136", "134", 
"250", "110", "112", "112", "110", "250", "250", "110", "136", 
"112", "112", "250", "110", "250", "136", "110", "112", "250", 
"136", "112", "136", "134", "136", "134", "138", "136", "134", 
"110", "112", "134", "250", "136", "138", "138", "136", "134", 
"138", "110", "250", "112", "138", "134", "138", "136", "134", 
"138", "136", "134", "136", "138", "138", "134", "136", "138", 
"134", "136", "134", "136", "138", "134", "138", "136", "134", 
"136", "136", "134", "134", "112", "136", "110", "250", "110", 
"138", "112", "110", "136", "134", "138", "138", "136", "134", 
"138", "136", "134", "136", "134", "138", "138", "112", "250", 
"110", "134", "136", "138", "112", "250", "112", "110", "250", 
"112", "110", "134", "134", "138", "136", "138", "134", "136", 
"138", "138", "136", "134", "250", "112", "110", "138", "138", 
"134", "136", "134", "136", "136", "134", "134", "136", "110", 
"112", "250", "136", "138", "134", "136", "136", "134", "110", 
"112", "250", "110", "250", "136", "112", "250", "112", "110", 
"136", "138", "250", "112", "110", "112", "110", "250", "136", 
"138", "134", "112", "110", "250", "136", "134", "112", "134", 
"136", "134", "136", "134", "136", "136", "138", "134", "250", 
"112", "138", "110", "112", "250", "110", "134", "112", "110", 
"250", "136", "138", "134", "136", "134", "138", "250", "110", 
"112", "134", "138", "136", "110", "112", "250", "136", "250", 
"110", "112", "136", "134", "138", "134", "138", "136", "110", 
"112", "110", "112", "112", "250", "110", "110", "112", "110", 
"250", "112", "138", "134", "136", "250", "110", "112", "112", 
"110", "250", "110", "250", "112", "138", "136", "138", "134", 
"134", "136", "138", "138", "136", "134", "134", "136", "138", 
"134", "136", "138", "136", "138", "134", "138", "136", "134", 
"136", "110", "136", "112", "250", "250", "110", "112", "110", 
"112", "250", "134", "136", "112", "250", "110", "250", "110", 
"112", "134", "136", "138", "138", "138", "134", "138", "136", 
"110", "250", "112", "136", "250", "110", "112", "138", "110", 
"138", "250", "112", "136", "134", "250", "110", "112", "136", 
"110", "112", "250", "138", "138", "138", "138", "138", "136", 
"134", "138", "138", "138", "110", "250", "112", "112", "250", 
"110", "112", "250", "110", "250", "112", "110", "136", "136", 
"138", "134", "136", "138", "134", "136", "134", "138", "138", 
"138", "138", "138", "134")), row.names = c(NA, -500L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000281a3641ef0>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should answer your problem. It is easy enough to resolve with a self-join in `tidyverse`, no need for the extra package `widyr` (which I didn't know)

```
library(dplyr)  #NB: use library(tidyverse) if you want full functionality

df_distinct <- sample.dat.sub %>% distinct(species_id, rgn_id)

inner_join(df_distinct, df_distinct , by="species_id", suffix=c("_1","_2")) %>% 
  filter(rgn_id_1 < rgn_id_2) %>% 
  group_by(rgn_id_1, rgn_id_2) %>% 
  summarise(nb_common_species = n())
```

Comment: Wow that is super easy and straightforward, thanks @Pierre Gramme! Didn't know about self joins in dplyr, very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Never used `widyr`. You can try something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df_res <- df %>% 
  group_by(rgn_id) %>% 
  summarise(species = list(unique(species_id)))

expand.grid(df_res$rgn_id, df_res$rgn_id) %>% 
  filter(as.integer(Var1) < as.integer(Var2)) %>% 
  mutate(
    n = map2(
      Var1, Var2, 
      ~length(
        intersect(
          filter(df_res, rgn_id == .x) %>% pluck("species", 1), 
          filter(df_res, rgn_id == .y) %>% pluck("species", 1)
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: This also works, I find the self-join option easier but it's good to know about expand.grid - I haven't used that before

Comment: keep in mind that joining on column which is not a key leads to cartesian product. By doing so, resulting table can have too much rows (if starting table is big enough).

Comment: hmm ok, I"m not sure what that means. Do you mean the self join can create memory allocation problems?